# How to create the + button with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

When you input "google" into Google, you will see there is a + button

> Show stock quote for GOOG

With firebug, you can see `<div class="csb mbi">`, what is the content of the class

> csb mbi

I want to create such a button,and after clicking it, it will become a - button. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with a +/- button, no images.  All text and CSS.

http://jsbin.com/ikeca

[image]

```
<html>

  <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Test Expander</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
          body { background-color: #FFF; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #000; }
          .hidden { display:none;}
          .indented {margin-left: 32px;}

          a.expander:active,
          a.expander:visited,
          a.expander:link {
          color: #0000CD;  /* ca2f2b; */
          text-decoration : none;

          /* display : block; */
          border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
          border-left: 1px dotted  #000;
          border-right: 1px dotted #000;
          border-top: 1px dotted  #000;
          padding: 1px;
          }

          a.expander:hover {
          color: #FF00FF;  /* FF00FF == Fuschia   #000; */
          text-decoration : none;
          background: #E6E6FA;  /* shading */ /* #f4f4f4; */
          padding: 1px;
          /* draw a shaded box around the thing when hovering */
          border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-left: 1px solid  #ccc;
          border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-top: 1px solid  #ccc;
          }

        </style>

      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <div id="div0">
          <p id="intro">
            <a href="#" class='expander'>+</a>
            Introduction</p>


          <p class='hidden indented' >
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer
            vulputate, nibh non rhoncus euismod, erat odio pellentesque lacus,
            sit amet convallis mi augue et odio. Phasellus cursus urna facilisis quam.
          </p>

          <p class='hidden indented' > Quisque pharetra lacus quis sapien. Duis
            id est non wisi sagittis adipiscing. Nulla facilisi. Etiam quam erat,
            lobortis eu, facilisis nec, blandit hendrerit, metus. Fusce
            hendrerit. Nunc magna libero, sollicitudin non, vulputate non, ornare
            id, nulla.  Suspendisse potenti. Nullam in mauris.
          </p>
        </div>


        <div id="div1">
          <p id="sec1">
            <a href="#" class='expander'>+</a>
            Section 1</p>


          <p class='hidden indented' >
            Vivamus congue pede at quam. Aliquam aliquam leo vel turpis. Ut
            commodo. Integer tincidunt sem a risus. Cras aliquam libero quis
            arcu. Integer posuere. Nulla malesuada, wisi ac elementum sollicitudin,
            libero libero molestie velit, eu faucibus est ante eu libero. Sed
            vestibulum, dolor ac ultricies consectetuer, tellus risus interdum diam,
            a imperdiet nibh eros eget mauris. Donec faucibus volutpat
            augue. Phasellus vitae arcu quis ipsum ultrices fermentum. Vivamus
            ultricies porta ligula. Nullam malesuada. Ut feugiat urna non
            turpis. Vivamus ipsum. Vivamus eleifend condimentum risus. Curabitur
            pede. Maecenas suscipit pretium tortor. Integer pellentesque.
          </p>
        </div>


        <div id="div2">
          <p id="sec2">
            <a href="#" class='expander'>+</a>
            Section 2</p>


          <p class='hidden indented' >
            Mauris est. Aenean accumsan purus vitae ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam at mauris id turpis placerat
            accumsan. Sed pharetra metus ut ante. Aenean vel urna sit amet ante
            pretium dapibus. Sed nulla. Sed nonummy, lacus a suscipit semper, erat
            wisi convallis mi, et accumsan magna elit laoreet sem. Nam leo est,
            cursus ut, molestie ac, laoreet id, mauris. Suspendisse auctor nibh.
          </p>

          <p class='hidden indented' >
            Nulla erat lorem, fringilla eget, ultrices nec, dictum sed,
            sapien. Aliquam libero ligula, porttitor scelerisque, lobortis nec,
            dignissim eu, elit. Etiam feugiat, dui vitae laoreet faucibus, tellus
            urna molestie purus, sit amet pretium lorem pede in erat.  Ut non libero
            et sapien porttitor eleifend.
          </p>

        </div>


      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The button is actually just an image. Google loads an image which contains a bunch of the links and images for their site and just adjusts the display of the background to show the piece they want to show.

These are the main styles needed to achieve what they're doing.

```
background:transparent url(/images/nav_logo7.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
height:13px;
overflow:hidden;
width:13px;
background-position:-91px -74px;
```

You can find all of this by examining the CSS when you're using FireBug.

Comment: What is the source of this image? I want to download it.

Comment: @Steven I hope you are aware that reusing this button in one of your project is most likely a violation of google copyright

Answer (score 0):

it's this image:

```
http://www.google.cz/images/nav_logo7.png
```

for inspecting those things, use firebug:

http://www.firebug.com