# How to prevent scrolling to the top after unhiding/hiding text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

There is an [old StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907799/how-to-create-the-button-with-css) on how to unhide/hide text using +/- symbols.

[Cheeso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48082/cheeso) posted a nice solution with some [sample code](http://jsbin.com/ikeca). It was just what I was looking for, although the original poster didn't agree. :-)

I'm using the code on a web site that is intended to be used on mobile devices. The only problem is that the page jumps back to the top of the screen whenever the +/- is tapped.

Is there anyway to get around that? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate... Seriously, please just use google. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697917/prevent-page-scroll-after-click http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601933/how-do-i-stop-a-web-page-from-scrolling-to-the-top-when-a-link-is-clicked-that-t http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139761/auto-scroll-stop-jumps-back-to-top-of-page

Comment: I'm actually posting to provide a solution. My first choice would have been to add a comment to the original answer, but the question has long since been closed.

Comment: right, but if someone came across that problem, a simple google would have answered the same query many, many times. There are three examples in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer that [Cheeso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48082/cheeso) provided to me in email. I am posting it here for the benefit of others who follow. This didn't quite work and I am in the process of figuring out why.

---

If you change this line
 $('div p a[href="#"]').click(function() { expando(this); });

to this:

$('div p a[href="#"]').click(function(ev) { ev.preventDefault(); expando(this); });

...I think it should stop scrolling to the top.

---

When a user clicks on a link that has a hash character, the browser is expected to scroll to the location on the page where the fragment marker is placed.   Like a bookmark.   For example, in this URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causes_of_WWII#Militarism  The fragment (bookmark) is #Militarism  , and if you click that link, your browser will scroll to that section.

In the case of that sample I wrote, the hrefs are bare # characters, which implies an empty fragment.  And I suppose the browser is scrolling to the default location, which (I guess) is "the top of the page".

To avoid this, just call ev.preventDefault() in the click handler.  This is a jQuery trick that suppresses the normal handling of the click; in your case, it suppresses the part where the browser tries to scroll to a non-existent anchor.

Comment: I got this to work under Chrome, but not Safari on my iPhone.

Comment: On my iPhone, this works under Atomic Web browser, but not Safari. It seems that this is an ongoing problem with mobile Safari. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664147/safari-mobile-ignoring-prevent-default

Comment: OK. It works under mobile Safari now. I reinstated a line from the original file: `<script src="/js/render/edit.js"></script>` The other browsers didn't seem to need it.

Answer (score 2):

In your click event handler, return false.

```
$('a.selector').click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in the click handler.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // more code here
});
```